# Getting the * selector in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

This may be a stupid question for you but I'm really curious what if getting the `*` in my css using jquery? Like for example:

css:

```
* {
   background: #fff;
}
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("*").css("color","#999999");
});
```

I have tested it and it doesn't work in jsfiddle. xD In my project it kinda work. All of my elements have `style="..."`.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lc1egayp/)**

Is there a work around there? Should I set another class for it? What is the best way to change that? Please don't tell me to change my css file for that. As much as possible I don't want to change the file that I didn't make in the first place. Any suggestions is much appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't include jQuery in your jsFiddle...

Comment: Ah. I'm sorry I forgot x.x

Comment: You should firstly always open your browser console to check for error

Comment: Yes I'm sorry. ( ˃̣̣̥ω˂̣̣̥ )

Comment: No problem... `( . Y . )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work in your fiddle because you haven't imported jQuery library,
and you have set the font color instead of the background-color.

But it works fine.

**[All selector doc](https://api.jquery.com/all-selector/)**

**Example**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("*").css("background-color","blue");
});
```

```css
*{
  background-color:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry that was a very clumsy of me to forget about the script. x.x Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use

```
* {
   background: #fff;
}
```

all developers which will use the code after you will thank you. CSS are heavily based on inheritance and behavior **cascading**. If you want everything to have a white background then just set it to the upper-most element and then set anomalies for the descendants. For example

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

If you want to select every element on the page you can for example do

```
$('body').find("*").css("color", "#000");
```

This can be however handled in a similar way, without the need to traverse the DOM with jQuery:

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
```

and then again, if you want some descendants to behave in a different manner then set them otherwise, below this setting in your CSS.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I was not the one who used it. It was already there and I'm the last one to edit this project so it is me that is having a hard time. :D

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the original file, you could also just load an additional CSS file below the original one with just the override. You might al so e.g.

```
/** overrides.css **/
* {
    background: red
}
```

Using jQuery or JavaScript to override has the huge downside that ALL elements are getting the style attached inline, which is kind of unnecessary.

Instead of targeting `*` you might as well add a specific class matching the language code to `body`, like `body.lang-de` via JS. Your CSS could then be:

```
body.lang-de * {
    background: red;
}
```

While in JS you play around with the [class manipulation methods](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/):

```
$('body').addClass('lang-de')
```

Comment: Yes that is a great idea but my project isn't like that. Its a bi-lingual site and I only needed to attach that override style when the language is changed and so what I thought is making it in jquery.

Comment: Updated my answer to provide a solution for that specific case.